# Creating a time stamp from a col of dates and a col of times in a data frame

Tags: r, date

i'm a beginner in R. I bet this question sounds stupid but its so specific i cannot find information in the internet.
I have to calculate process times from a data frame. The problem is, the dataframe has a col of dates and a col of times. Is there an easy possibility for me to merge them to get a time stamp without using loops?

Comment: Please show us a reproducible example and it's expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this data example:

```
df <- data.frame(day = as.Date(c("2018-07-25", "2018-07-24")),
                 times = c("05:24:36", "11:27:14"))

         day    times
1 2018-07-25 05:24:36
2 2018-07-24 11:27:14
```

Now use `paste` in combination with `as.POSIXct` to create a timestamp variable with a vectorized operation.

```
df$ts <- as.POSIXct(paste(df$day, df$times, sep = " "))

         day    times                  ts
1 2018-07-25 05:24:36 2018-07-25 05:24:36
2 2018-07-24 11:27:14 2018-07-24 11:27:14
```

Comment: Perhaps add the usage to define the format, if the dates and times are not in the standard or not yet stored in the correct datatype. `df$ts <- as.POSIXct(paste(df$day, df$times, sep = " "), tryFormats = c("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"))`

Comment: Thank you. I tried a bit around with this solution. It should work for me!

Comment: `paste` by default has `sep = " "`